# Multi touch support on a multi window Electron app

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, touch, touch-event

I have an Electron app that generate 4 different Browser Window:

```js
// Create number of window specified in windowsNumber
for (let index = 0; index < windowsNumber; index++) {

    //Create screen
    let screen = new BrowserWindow({
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            partition: 'persist:win' + index,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    //Load screen content
    if (process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
        screen.loadURL(process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
    } else {
        screen.loadFile(`.output/public/index.html`);
    }

}
```

These 4 windows goes to 4 touch screen monitor.

The problem it's that when I perform a touch gesture on one monitor, the others don't listen their gesture anymore.

Seems that Electron is able to handle only one touch gesture at time in all the application.

It's possible to configure Electron (or develop a custom way) to handle the gesture of all window simultaneously and independently?